# I want to replace only certain characters of a string using powershell

Tags: string, powershell, networking, replace, scripting

I am writing a powershell script that uses the ip address to generate the network address (`10.12.142.12` to `10.12.142.0`) All of the ip addresses that I will be handling follow the following format `10.xxx.xxx.12`

I have tried using the [`String.Replace()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace). It works until the ip address is something like the following `10.12.154.12` or `10.214.126.12`. It grabs and replaces all the `.12`. Ive also tried some regex, but couldn't come up with an expression that matches only the last octet.

```
$ipAddress = "10.12.23.12"
$networkNumber = $ipAddress.replace(".12",".0")
```

I want `10.12.23.0`, but I get `10.0.23.0`

Answer (score 4):

Either remove everything from the last `.` with `String.Remove()` and `String.LastIndexOf()`, then add `.0`:

```
$ipAddress = "10.12.23.12"
$network = $ipAddress.Remove($ipAddress.LastIndexOf('.')) + '.0'
```

or use a regular expression that only replace `.12` *at the end* of the string:

```
$ipAddress = "10.12.23.12"
$network = $ipAddress -replace '\.\d{1,3}$','.0'
```

Both of these will work with any value in the last octet, not just `.12`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `Split` and `Join` methods on string:

```
$ipAddress = "10.12.23.12"
$parts = $ipAddress.Split(".")
$parts[3] = "0"
$networkNumber = [String]::Join(".", $parts)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to extract the substring before and including the last `.` with `Substring()` and `LastIndexOf()`, then concatenate with `0`:

```
PS C:\> $ipAddress = "10.12.23.12"                                                              
PS C:\> $ipAddress.Substring(0, $ipAddress.LastIndexOf('.') + 1) + '0'
10.12.23.0
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably overkill, but since the network address is directly related to the subnet mask, this function will take that into account.

```
Function Get-NetAddress {
    param($IPAddress,$SubnetMask)

    $IPArray = $IPAddress -split "\."
    $MaskArray = $SubnetMask -split "\."
    $output = for ($i = 0; $i -lt 4; $i++) {
        $IPArray[$i] -band $MaskArray[$i]
    }
    $output -join "."
}
```

**Output Samples:**

```
Get-NetAddress 192.168.7.1 255.255.248.0
192.168.0.0

Get-NetAddress 10.20.30.40 255.255.0.0
10.20.0.0

Get-NetAddress 10.20.30.250 255.255.255.0
10.20.30.0

Get-NetAddress 10.20.30.171 255.255.255.224
10.20.30.160
```